# Passing the directory name with date and timestamp in Azure pipelines copy files task

Tags: maven, unit-testing, azure-devops

I have Currently setup an Azure pipeline which runs the test cases using maven and generates hmtl reports of the test cases inside a Directory name with date and time stamp

Ex: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Results/Run_10-Jan-2021_11-55-34_AM/HTML Results/*.html`

While trying to export these html reports as pipeline artifacts using copy files task and Publish artifacts task, how do I add this directory (With name and time stamp) in the path to copy files ? I tried as below, but I keep on getting the error file or directory not found.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Results/**/HTML Results/'
    Contents: '*.html'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

After the pipeline runs all the html files will be in the below path

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Results/Run_10-Jan-2021_11-55-34_AM/HTML Results/
```

Here directory Run_10-jan-2021_11-55-34_AM name changes after every pipeline run, For example if I run the pipeline today it would be

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Results/Run_11-Jan-2021_13-50-30_PM/HTML Results/
```

So my question is how do I pass this directory name with out changing the copy files task every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to find all .html files, and copy it to the folder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Results/Run_10-Jan-2021_11-55-34_AM/HTML Results`, then publish it as Artifacts

Such as

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Results/**/HTML Results/'
    Contents: '*.html'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Results/Run_10-Jan-2021_11-55-34_AM/HTML Results'


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Result:

[image]

**Update1**

We could not use ** in the path, we could use it in the field contents. Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#goal) for more details.

Sample:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    Contents: |
      $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Results/**/HTML Results/*.html
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: My question was how to add the directory with name and time stamp (which gets created after every pipeline run) in the source folder path

Comment: I don’t want directory with date and time stamp in the drop folder, instead since the directory gets after every run, how do I pass it as variable in source folder path Run_$(date)_$(time) this way

Comment: The file was created while the pipeline was running, right?

Comment: Yes how do I pass it in the source folder path to automatically pick the directory created, bcoz it changes every time, after every run.

Comment: Hi @saikumarreddy, It seems that we specified a wrong directory path, could you please check it and ensure that the directory path is correct and the .xml file exists? Thanks.

Comment: In addition, do you customize MSBuild Arguments or outputpath in the csporj file to change the output file path?

Comment: Yes .HTML files are inside $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Results/Directorywithtimeanddate/HTML Results/

Comment: Am trying to do this way in copy files task using $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Results/**/HTML Results/, but I get the error no directory found, instead of ** how do I pass the directory which gets created with date and time stamp after every run is my question

Comment: Hi @saikumarreddy, We could not use ** in the path, we could use it in the field contents. I have updated the answer, you could check the update1 and then share the result here.

Comment: Hi@Vito Liu-MSFT, Updated my question with the details at the bottom.

Comment: Hi @saikumarreddy, could you please try my update1 answer to copy the files and then share the result here? I have tested it, It should work.

Comment: Hi @saikumarreddy, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?